# Properties of Invertible System

Tags: continuous-signals

I have come to the understanding that if these three properties hold true then the system is a memory system:

1) Time Scaling:

$$y(t)=x(2t)\,,$$

2) Time Shifting:

$$y(t)=x(t+2)\,,$$

3) Integration based system.

I want to ask that do these properties also hold true for invertible systems?

Comment: You list two properties and a system type. That is not "three properties". And I don't think you've fully understood the concept of a memory(less) system, to be honest, based on your other two questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of signal processing, a continuous-time system

$$y(t) = \mathcal{T} \{ x(t) \}$$

is said to have **memory** if its output at time $t=t_0$ has a dependency on the input values for any time other than $t=t_0$. Otherwise; if the output at time $t = t_0$ depends only on the input value at time $t=t_0$, then it's a **memoryless** system.

So the system defined by:
$$y(t) = x(2t)$$ 
has memory, which can be proven by a single example, as $y(t)$ at $t=5$ is given by $x(t)$ at $t=10$...

Furthermore, a system is **invertible** if unique (distinct) inputs produce unique (distinct) outputs, otherwise it not invertible.

So the continuous time system defined by:
$$y(t) = x(2t)$$ 
is invertible, as its inverse is given by $x(t) = y(t/2)$.

Comment: How would you include the system $y(t)=dx(t)/dt$ in your definition of systems with and without memory?

Comment: The differentiator requires multiple values of x(t) $$ x'(t) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ x(t+h)-x(t)}{h} $$So it has memory as it depends on the value of input at time $t + h$ . I'm sure you ask it for the **limiting** case...so that's memoryless in the limit :-). Then I would ask you @MattL. to classify this system: $$ y(t) = \lim_{h \to 0} x(t)^{1 + h} $$ is it **linear** or **nonlinear** ? :-)

Comment: It's not about challenging each other (the system you ask about is linear, BTW), but it's about the important case of differentiation and its classification in terms of system memory, which is what the original question is about. And I haven't seen a satisfactory discussion of a differentiator yet.

Comment: @MattL. No it was not a challenge because if that system is linear (according to limit behaviour), then the differentiator should be memoryless, according to limit behaviour. But I haven't also seen a discussion of it anywhere, may be because it's not that important in practice...? (BTW: you would need an inductor or capacitor to implement a differentiator and those elements are energy storing types which posses memory...)